# Visual Studios Report Builder - is there a way to add a condition to the PrintOnLastPage element (boolean) of a report Footer?

Tags: visual-studio, reportbuilder

New to Visual Studio report project. I am trying to get the PrintOnLastPage element to only be true when a specific other element is Hidden. But, I am getting the following error:

Deserialization failed: The `'PrintOnLastPage'` element is invalid - The value... is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:boolean' - The string `'=IIF(Parameters!WOLform.Visibility.Hidden.value=true, true, false)'` is not a valid Boolean value. (I condensed this error message)

I know it wants the value to be either true or false, but is there a way to get this to be conditional? Or, am I just writing it completely wrong, or is this just impossible with current Visual Studio?

```
<Rectangle Name="WOLform">

<Visibility>
  <Hidden>=IIF(my condition, true, false)</Hidden>
</Visibility>

<PageFooter>

<PrintOnLastPage>
=IIF(Parameters!WOLform.Visibility.Hidden.value=true, true, false)
</PrintOnLastPage>
```

I have tried adding a  element inside but also get an error stating that the element does not allow child elements).

Desired Result: This WOL form is sometimes the last page of my report, depending on certain other conditions. If this page displays, then I do not want the Footer to show on this last page.